# how to restore unbootable drive using testdisk

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk

I accidentally erased my sister's entire hard drive and made a new partition table while tying to formate a USB and now the laptop gives me this screen on boot up

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUsSg.jpg

I now have a persistent live USB with Ubuntu 16.04 and I've installed testdisk on it.

Can anyone plase help me and give me simple instructions to recover the HDD again?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you, if possible,to first make a disk image and only then to try an recovery tool. This is to allow for multiple attempts without risking too much (you already did!).

I personally prefer to use `safecopy` to create such a disk image. It's not slower than the usual `dd` but it can also attempt for multiple strategies in case the disk has hardware failures. The disk image files will allow you different recovery attempts, even the more destructive ones.

Then, in cases like yours, I'd give `foremost` a try as it can attempt for an automatic recovery of whatever is available on that disk image.

`testdisk` is also a good tool, though, but with different aims and features.

The fewer operation you performed on that disk after the format, the higher the chances you can recover almost every file.

I'd suggest you to follow `testdisk` [wiki](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) to perform the recovery.